# Multipart upload to AWS S3 fails Boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

Trying to upload a file to AWS S3 using Boto and their s3put script fails without much information why.

Upon pool.join() I print mp.get_all_parts() and compare it with the number of chunks the file has been broken into. It shows 0 parts versus 17 chunks.

The last output of the debug from Boto is where I'm confused, why would it be deleting an uploadId?

```
send: u'DELETE /<bucket>/<path>?uploadId=<uploadID> HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: s3.amazonaws.com\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nDate: Mon, 04 Jan 2016 16:35:14 GMT\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\nAuthorization: AWS <awsAccess>:<awsSecret>=\r\nUser-Agent: Boto/2.38.0 Python/2.7.6 Linux/3.13.0-48-generic\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 204 No Content\r\n'
header: x-amz-id-2: <id>
header: x-amz-request-id: <request>
header: Date: Mon, 04 Jan 2016 16:38:46 GMT
header: Server: AmazonS3
```

Comment: Multipart upload required 5MB minimum size for each part and 10K total number of part. In general boto/s3 do multipart smoothly if you have followed above constraints.

Comment: The file was >1GB however I do not think it had more than 10K parts. Why such a high number of individual chunks?